# Why do our network does not have internet when adding a route?

Tags: routing, openvpn, internet, gateway

We have 2 Networks.
The first is an OpenVPN server with the Network 10.170
The second is a Gateway-Server for our laptops, printers etc. on Network 10.133.10.1
It haves the OpenVPN-IP 10.170.0.19

The Connection between them is stable, but as soon as i add an routing, all clients within the 2nd network do not have internet.
The connection between the 2 servers is still stable and i also can reach the devices in network 2 from the 1st netwerk, but there, windows shows "No Internet Connection" and we cant open any website.

The routing command i used on 10.133.10.1 is: `ip route add 10.133.10.0/24 via 10.170.0.19 dev tun0`. I do it manually since i found out, this causes the error. Before, we had `route 10.133.10.0 255.255.255.0` in the clients config.

What can cause this error and how could this be fixed?

edit:
[image: This is the Situation]

Comment: Is the default gateway inside 10.133.10.0/24 such that your route statement causes traffic bound for remote destinations to go the wrong way?

Comment: The default gateway is the 10.133.10.1

Comment: That route is plainly wrong for that end of the VPN connection.

Comment: @TimoTreichel So that steers all internet traffic to 10.170.0.19. Does 10.170.0.19 have any idea what to do with that traffic?

Comment: @DavidSchwartz actually, the traffic from network 2 to network 1 is not intended ... the vpn and routing is for network 1 to be able to use the printers ... there is a default routing from 10.133.10.1 to 192.168.178.1 which is the router

Comment: The Clients, which lose the internet (Laptops, Printers) are all in the network 10.133.10.0/24

Comment: @TimoTreichel So you are asking a machine inside 10.133.10.0/24 to use 10.170.0.19 to reach other machines inside 10.133.10.0/24? That doesn't seem right.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz wait, does that mean, i have to do the `ip route add 10.133.10.0/24 via 10.170.0.19 dev tun0` on Network 1??? if so, why do the maschines of network 1 can reach the printers after i add this routing on network 2?

Comment: By network 2 do you mean `Gateway Server` or its LAN hosts? Is `Gateway Server` the "default gateway" of the LAN hosts? What's the prefix length / subnet mask used on them?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

In the end i found out, that my kollegue renamed the key, but forgot to rename the CCD-File. After renaming this file, everything works flawless.

Answer (score 1):

The reason that route causes Internet access not to work is that it routes Internet traffic in the wrong direction. When 10.133.10.1 receives packets from the Internet, it needs to send them directly to machines in the 10.133.10.0/24 network. Your route tells it to send those packets to 10.170.0.19. With that route in place, there is no way packets from the Internet could get to any machine in the 10.133.10.0/24 network other than 10.133.10.1.

To get traffic where it needs to go, you can either enter an appropriate route on the origin machine or you can let the traffic follow that machine's default route and add an appropriate route on the router. The latter course is probably better.

So the printer, 10.133.10.41, needs to reach machines in the 10.170.0.0/24 network through 10.133.10.1. But we don't want to add a route for every device on the 10.133.10.0/24 network, so we can do it on the 10.133.10.1 machine, since that's where they'll send the traffic now. So we need a route on 10.133.10.1 to send packets bound for 10.170.0.0/24 to 10.170.0.1.

We need return traffic too. So 10.170.0.2 needs to reach machines in the 10.133.10.0/24 network through 10.170.0.19. But we don't want to add a route on every device, so we can do it on 10.170.0.1, telling it to send packets bound for 10.133.10.0/24 to 10.170.0.19.

It's possible the latter route is already set up automatically be the OpenVPN server because it should know that 10.133.10.0/24 is reachable through the VPN. So you may only need to add the first route.

So I think all you have wrong is that 10.133.10.0/24 in the `ip route` command should be 10.70.0.0/24.

Answer (score 0):

Honest question, not being snarky: Why would you need routes if the gateway server is connected to both networks?

That notwithstanding, do you have a return route to the 10.170.0.0/24 network? I think you would probably need to add `ip route 10.170.0.0/24 via 10.133.10.1`.

Answer (score 0):

Whether you need to add a route for `10.133.10.0/24` on `OVPN Server` depends on:

1. whether you need `OVPN Server` **itself** to be able to reach the `10.133.10.0/24` hosts
2. whether you are relying on the `client-to-client` OpenVPN feature
3. whether you need traffics from *other* hosts (e.g. the Internet) to be able to go (back) to the `10.133.10.0/24` hosts. **(This is probably true in your case since apparently you want the `10.133.10.0/24` hosts to use `OVPN Server`'s Internet access as theirs.)**

Either way the gateway / nexthop of the `10.133.10.0/24` route if added would be **bogus / optional**.

Assuming true for `2.`, what you need for the VPN clients to be able to reach `10.133.10.0/24` would be **only**:

1. route for `10.133.10.0/24` pushed to / configured on the VPN clients, with the tun interface as the route interface (nexthop / gateway is *bogus* for L3 VPN)
2. `iroute` for `10.133.10.0/24` in the *CCD* (See `--client-config-dir` in the OpenVPN manual) file *for* `Gateway Server` *on* `OVPN Server`, which is the (only) way to make traffics with destination IP that is NOT the corresponding VPN client IP go to a VPN client host (CCD file with `iroute` can be seen as the tun-mode OpenVPN way of implementing the the idea of nexthop / gateway)

**(Note that the above are needed anyway regardless of whether `client-to-client` is used; It's just if that is not used, you would need *more* than those.)**

You do not need any extra route added on `Gateway Server` or its LAN hosts. The subnet / prefix routes of the two networks it is connected to should be sufficient for all the desired communication.

(Well, the only extra one you need on `Gateway Server` is a `default` route or equivalent that has the tun as the route interface, which will be added in an appropriate way when you use `redirect-gateway`, with `def1` or not. Similarly I assumed that `Gateway Server` is the "default gateway" of the LAN hosts.)

The one thing that is **for sure wrong** is adding a route for the LAN subnet (`10.133.10.0/24`) with **ANY** nexthop / gateway on `Gateway Server` or any of its LAN hosts.

---

AFAICR, when you do not use `client-to-client`, traffics from VPN clients will "escape" from OpenVPN program / tunnel even if the destination is a client's IP or an IP that is covered by an `iroute`, in which case you need the VPN server to have corresponding route (in your case, `10.133.10.0/24`, again the nexthop / gateway is bogus / optional) that loops the traffics back in concern back to the tunnel, which involves IP forwarding of the OS network stack. Therefore IP forwarding needs to be enabled (sysctl) and allowed (firewall) in that case. **These also applies if `OVPN Server` is used for the LAN hosts' / VPN clients' Internet access.**

---

Also make sure you do NOT NAT / IP masquerade for the LAN hosts on `Gateway Server` (at least exempt traffics that destined at `10.170.0.0/24`). Otherwise replies from them to the VPN clients will have `10.133.10.1` as the source address and the corresponding program will not recognize them as replies. Instead, make sure traffics with source within `10.133.10.0/24` are NAT'd / IP masqueraded on `OVPN server` if the traffics are destined at the Internet or so.